# How to batch add to collection in angular firestore?

Tags: angular, angularfire

How to batch add to collection in angular firestore?

Following function tries to create new users inside a collection:

```
  batchCreate() {
    const batch = this.firestore.collection('users').ref.firestore.batch();


    this.users.forEach((user) => {
      const ref: any = this.firestore
        .collection('users')


// even if  reference a doc like this (it doesnot works):
//      const ref: any = this.firestore
//        .collection('users').doc(user.id)


//this collection and documents doesnot exists on the db.

      batch.set(ref, user);
    });

batch.commit()
  }
```

But the above logic is not working.

Not sure why!

The idea was to create a collection (which formally doesnot exists but created on the go), and push the whole list of users in a single transaction, instead of single post requests. Is that possible?

**The idea was to bulk add or update a collection**

Comment: Why not use transactions??

Comment: Collections cannot be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const batch = this.firestore.firestore.batch();
this.users.forEach(user => {
    const insert = this.firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.id).ref; // Don't forget this ".ref"
    batch.set(insert, user);
});
return batch.commit();
```